# how to specify the output path in R

Tags: r, sink

I am new to R language. I am writing a program in spark with R. I want to save the output to the hdfs path.I tried the `sink` method

```
sink("/user/new/output/test.txt")
```

but it throws an error. Any help will be appreciated.

The exact error message is

```
error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
cannot open the connection
Calls: sink -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
cannot open file '/user/new/output/text.txt': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: The specified file is not exist

Comment: maybe try with `sink("/user/new/output/test.txt")` at the beginning of your script and `sink("/user/new/output/test.txt", append=TRUE)` at the end

Comment: any other possible ways to save the output to the specified path?

Comment: in run time only i am going to create the output file

Comment: Does the directory `/user/new/output/` exist?

Comment: If it's a data.frame or something, write.table could work

Comment: it is not a data frame

Answer (score 1):

This error is shown when the directory containing the file `test.txt` you want to sink to does not exist. You can create it within R (if you have write permissions):

```
dir.create("/user/new/output/test.txt")
```

Comment: so if i use dir.create shall i drop the sink method or i need to specify sink also

Comment: You should also sink. Your error looks like the directory `/user/new/output` does not yet exist. So call `dir.create`  before you call `sink`